# How to check if a value is in an array, inside an if condition, in jquery templates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, jquery-templates

I have a jQuery template and I need to check the checkboxes in a list whose value is inside the array. I'm trying the following code, but it's not working:

```
{{each loginProvidersList}}
  {{if inArray($value.Id, settings.LoginProviders) }}
    <input id="${$value.Id}" type="checkbox" name="LoginProviders[]" value="${$value.Id}" checked="checked" /> ${$value.Name}<br />                     
  {{else}}
    <input id="${$value.Id}" type="checkbox" name="LoginProviders[]" value="${$value.Id}" /> ${$value.Name}<br />                     
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

settings.LoginProviders contains an array with the values that have been loaded from the database

Comment: settings.LoginProviders - is it a javascript array ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.

First of all inArray doesn't return a boolean, but the index where the items is (-1 if it is not found). Also, I forgot the $ at the beginning of the function. The correct code is this:

```
{{each loginProvidersList}}
  {{if $.inArray($value.Id, settings.LoginProviders) != -1 }}
    <input id="${$value.Id}" type="checkbox" name="LoginProviders[]" value="${$value.Id}" checked="checked" /> ${$value.Name}<br />                     
  {{else}}
    <input id="${$value.Id}" type="checkbox" name="LoginProviders[]" value="${$value.Id}" /> ${$value.Name}<br />                     
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```